# Convolution Verbs & IP Softwares

Tags: impulse-response, convolution-reverb

Hey everyone,

I'm very interested in getting into recording my own IP's, mashing sounds, collecting pro IP libraries, etc.

I'm wondering which softwares you guys think are the best?

- Altiverb
- SIR2
- etc ?

Are there some less expensive ones that still produce good results, if I want to get started but can't afford Altiverb off the bat??

Thanks!!!

Comment: I didn't realize that TL spaces was a convolution reverb. It it any good? Has anyone used it?

Comment: I'd say B+/A- for quality of results, F for RTAS/automated reliability in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the only ones I've tried that I like is Audioease Altiverb and Steinberg REVerence. Altiverb has a little more emphasis on the lower mid, and REVerence the higher.

Waves was WAY to sharp for me, and seemed to lack a little in resolution, and the SIR-verbs generally sounded too much like a cheap Behringer pedal for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jun06/articles/qa0606_1.htm) is an article from Sound on Sound on the difference between convolution reverbs.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two cross-platform/ multi-format options that I've been particularly happy with:

Liquidsonics Reverberate - £50/ $75 - http://www.liquidsonics.com/home.htm

Meldaproduction MMultibandConvolution - €21/ $25 - http://www.meldaproduction.com/mcreativebundle/mmultibandconvolution.php

And if you're a Mac user, there's always Logic Pro ($199, Mac App Store) and Space Designer -- I'm not a Logic user (in fact, I rather loather having to use it... but that's another discussion) but I've long loved Space Designer and place a much higher value on it than TLSpace, Alitverb or IR. The only issue is jumping through hoops to be able to use Space Designer in other applications. Please, Apple make Audio Unit versions of Logic Plugins. (Or make Logic useable. Either one.)